# Moving a staging site to live (Wordpress) by using a backup

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, phpmyadmin, database-restore, staging

I have a wordpress installation on let's say www.mysite.com. I used a plugin to create a staging site which is located under www.mysite.com/staging. After doing my changes I made a full backup including the database, went back to mysite.com and imported the backup. End of story: error 500 everywhere and I cannot login to the backend anymore because I have an endless redirect:

"Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Everytime I call mysite.com it redirects to mysite.com/mysite/staging. I could ask my hoster to recover the website but I would like to understand what went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you try to open the database and correct the values of `site_url` and `home` in `wp_options` table? Else try these options: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Instead of taking backup and upload it, use duplicator plugin of wordpress to migrate it, it will be a lot easier and error free. @CamrynHayes

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have correctly migrated your entire WP files and imported the database into your mysite domain, login to phpMyAdmin and locate your site mysite.com database. Open the tables and find wp-options. Look for the following tables

1. siteurl
2. home

Update their values with your new URL which is mysite.com.

Now visit your site and you should see no redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Unfortunately renaming the siteurl and home doesn't help, still the same problem.